# MySQL stops every day after "Started ACPI event daemon"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

```
systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
systemd[1]: Reloading.
systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
systemd[1]: Reloading.
systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL 5.7.20 Community Server...
systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL 5.7.20 Community Server.
kernel: [420109.677234] audit: type=1400 audit(1512740048.434:73): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=15127 comm="apparmor_parser"
kernel: [420109.697629] audit: type=1400 audit(1512740048.454:74): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/15146/status" pid=15146 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
kernel: [420109.697657] audit: type=1400 audit(1512740048.454:75): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=15146 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
kernel: [420109.697692] audit: type=1400 audit(1512740048.454:76): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/15146/status" pid=15146 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
kernel: [420109.806977] audit: type=1400 audit(1512740048.562:77): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=15160 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue, but in my case it is not ever day, but every week or so. Did you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In short: it's an autoupdate of mysql-server-5.7,
that fails because of new structure of config files.
You can check it manually by trying to update it:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
```

It will show you such error message:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
```

**Solution**:

Copy the config file with its old name:

```
cp my.cnf.fallback mysql.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

To everyone ending here but /etc/mysql/FROZEN isn't set and 5.7 is already at the newest version without update issues:

Please check your Logs slightly earlier. It may contain

```
systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
```

If you want to get rid of that (see https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/enable-disable-unattended-upgrades-ubuntu-16-04/):

```
sudo apt-get remove unattended-upgrades
sudo systemctl stop apt-daily.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service
```

**Be aware, this command might cause the same restart of mysqld and others, too.**

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```